# Cosa vuol dire "dare secche" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ma la sera e la notte molti pensarono che era forse meglio che i partigiani non l’**avessero date tanto secche** ai fascisti, perché poteva darsi che si dovesse poi pagare il conto.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "dare tanto secche" nel contesto di questa frase? Ho cercato alle voci "secco" e "secca" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Comment: Darle secche (riferito alle botte) vuol dire picchiare con particolare violenza e in senso più generale causare una pesante sconfitta all'avversario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Darle secche (riferito alle botte) vuol dire picchiare con particolare violenza e in senso più generale cagionare una pesante sconfitta all'avversario.

Per [secche](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/secco) da Wiktionary:

> prenderle secche, **darle secche**, sott. le botte: essere picchiato,
>   **picchiare duramente**